# Use a generated string for an array in MySQL with variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to use a generated string as an array within a MySQL-Loop.
The string/array is built into `$argumentarray` from the `$rows` arguments and should after be used as the array of `multiSQLarray[]`

The function is called as:

```
multiSQL('**id,title,description,link**','menu')
```

The string gets correctly generated as

```
array('id' => $result['id'],'title' => $result['title'],'description' => $result['description'], 'link' => $result['link'])
```

But instead of using it as a string for the array it just adds it to the array for every result from the sql

```
Array ( [0] => array('id' => $result['id'],'title' => $result['title'],'description' => $result['description'], 'link' => $result['link']) [1] => array('id' => $result['id'],'title' => $result['title'],'description' => $result['description'], 'link' => $result['link']) )
```

What i expect is the SQL result as the array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => Customers [description] => Display the Customer Dashboard [link] => index.php ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => Server [description] => Display all Servers [link] => servers.php ) )
```

My code:

```
function multiSQL($rows=null,$table=null,$select=null) {
    if(is_null($select)) {$filter="";} else { $filter = ' where '.$select; }
    global $pdo;
    $sql = 'SELECT '.$rows.' FROM '.$table.$filter.'';
    $connection =$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $connection->execute();
    $multiSQLarray = array();
    $arguments = explode(',',$rows);
    $argumentarray = "";
    $argumentscount=count($arguments);
    $loopcount = 1;
    foreach($arguments as $argument){

            if($loopcount==$argumentscount){
            $loopcount++;
            $argumentarray = $argumentarray.' \''.$argument.'\' => $result[\''.$argument.'\']';

            }
            else{
                $loopcount++;
            $argumentarray = $argumentarray.'\''.$argument.'\' => $result[\''.$argument.'\'],';
            }
    }
    $argumentarray = 'array('.$argumentarray.')';
    echo $argumentarray.'<br><br>';
    while ($result = $connection->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        //$multiSQLarray[] = array('id' => $result['id'], 'title'  => $result['title'], 'description'  => $result['description'], 'link'  => $result['link']);
        $multiSQLarray[] = $argumentarray;
        }
    print_r($multiSQLarray);
    return $multiSQLarray;
```

Comment: Confused by the string manipulation. Are you struggling with how to work with arrays? Also, `if($loopcount==$argumentscount){` makes no sense to me.

Comment: No, im fine with arrays in general. just looking for a way to use the generated string as the "array" definition to fill the mysql result in the array. The //$multiSQLarray where the string is in plaintext works fine. But i need to have it dynamically generated as the input arguments will always be different, i cant have it static. The if($loopcount...) is used so the last element in the array-string doenst have a"," at the end.

Comment: For example the input could also be multiSQL('id,name,email','customers') and therefore the array should be built as array('id' => $result['id'],'name' => $result['name'], 'email' => $result['email'])

Comment: Huh? Worry more about the building of the SQL expression. The resultset can be an associative array by default. That looping over the result the query returns should not be needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Structured data is structured data. Be it in a string or an array. I can't make sense of some of your code. The arrays in strings... unless you are angling to use an eval. I think that bit confuses your question some.

One thing you need to consider is how exposed you will be to SQL injection. Basically never trust the user right? So, you could do things like predfine, in code, the allowed columns. If the form submitted references something not whitelisted then stop! Also, have to think about escaping the user supplied values.

I'd want my function to accept a known, arguments that make sense for what it needs passed in... Clean things up first and then pass some data types that make the most sense to the function. Maybe something like...

```
/**
 * @param string $table
 * @param array $fields
 * @param array $criteria (key/value pairs where key is field and value is scalar)
 */
function buildQuery($table, $fields, $criteria) {

    $where = [];
    $whereVals = [];
    foreach($criteria as $k => $v) {
        $where[] = "({$k} = ?)";
        $whereVals[] = $v;
    }
    $where = implode(' AND ', $where);


    $fields = implode(', ', $fields);

    $sql = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table} WHERE {$where}";
    //eg. SELECT id, name, bar FROM fooTable WHERE (id = ?) AND (name = ?)

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $retval = $query->execute($whereVals);

    return $retval;
}

$response = buildQuery( 'fooTable', 
                        ['id', 'name', 'bar'], 
                        [   
                            'id' => 5, 
                            'name' => 'john'
                        ]);
```

Maybe look at some frameworks or an ORM like Doctrine? Can see some good examples of OOP representations of a select statement. Makes dynamic query building a lot easier. End up with something DRYer too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this is a bit too high for my knowledge. And as its only an internal tool for 2 people the sql-injection part should be safe to ignore. Also the input comes from the static-code and not from any input fields. I added a new answer without the whole looping, hoping to clarfiy what i want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. Would love to help more but not even sure anymore where you are stuck or what specifically you are asking. Welcome to SO and best of luck!